# git coloring for the show-branch command

Tags: git

When you do a git show-branch with more than 3 or so branches, it can be difficult to track which branch is which in the columns on the left.  Git provides a colorization option to use different colors for different branches, which helps when the colors are visible, but much of the time it chooses colors that are invisible against the terminal background color.

Git has zillions of options, so there must be a way to tell it what colors to use, but how?  The only config var that shows up in the docs is color.showBranch, so I tried:

```
[color]
    showBranch = red blue green
```

in my .gitconfig file, but that just gives me

```
fatal: bad numeric config value 'red blue green' for 'color.showbranch': invalid unit
```

Comment: The `git config` doc says `A boolean to enable/disable color in the output of git-show-branch(1). May be set to always, false (or never) or auto (or true), in which case colors are used only when the output is to a terminal. If unset, then the value of color.ui is used (auto by default).` (I don't actually use `git show-branch` myself, hence have no idea if you can make it sing and dance differently.)

Answer (score 0):

The following is drawn from https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

In fact `git` doesn't have zillions of colors to choose from, as it's limited in the assumptions it makes about terminal capabilities.  It has 16 colors that work with just about anything, and up to 256 if the terminal supports ANSI-256 color mode.

(When I say "16", that's 8 basic colors - red blue green yellow magenta cyan white - at two intensities (normal and bold) that just about everything can do.  git also accepts other modifiers, like "dim", "ul", "blink", "strike", etc.  If your terminal does something visibly distinct with those settings, that's additional options.)

You can set colors for the branch command with these options:

```
color.branch.local
color.branch.current
color.branch.remote
color.branch.upstream
color.branch.plain
```

Their values are things like *green black* (green on black background), or *red bold white* (bold red on white background)

Comment: I tried setting those, but they have no apparent effect on `git show-branch`